# Retrieve info from Word tables

Tags: vba, ms-word, range

I've got a Word document with a section surrounded by hidden text tags < Answers > ...some tables... < /Answers >. A Word macro can return the range of the text between these tags (used to be bookmarks but they had to go).

What I want to do from Excel is open the Word document, get the range between the tags, iterate the tables in that block and retrieve some cells from each row. Those cell data is then written in some rows on a new Excel sheet.

I saw many Word/Excel automation but none that inspired me to retrieve that range between two pieces of text. Best would be to be able to run the Word macro RetrieveRange(strTagName, rngTextBlock) in Word to return the range in rngTextBlock for "Answers" but this seems impossible.

As background: the .docm file is an exam paper with answers and maximum points that I 'd like to transfer into Excel to contain gradings for each student.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing though some more sites, I encountered a C# example that partly did what I needed: rather than using Word's SELECTION stick to ranges to find something. I now can find the text block between the two tags, but still fail on traversing its tables and table rows. No compiler error (and working in Word itself) but I must be missing an external link...

```
Function CreateSEWorksheet() As Boolean
  ' Find <ANSWERS> in Word Document, and traverse all tables and write them as rows in worksheet

  Dim wdrngStart As Word.Range
  Dim wdrngEnd As Word.Range
  Dim wdrngAnswers As Word.Range
  Dim wdTable As Word.Table
  Dim wdRow As Word.Row
  Dim strStr As String
  Dim bGoOn As Boolean

' Following set elsewhere:
' Set WDApp = GetObject(class:="Application.Word")
' Set WDDoc = WDApp.Documents.Open(filename:="filespec", visible:=True)

  Set wdrngStart = WDDoc.Range  ' select entire document - will shrink later
  Set wdrngEnd = WDDoc.Range
  Set wdrngAnswers = WDDoc.Range

  ' don't use Word SELECT/SELECTION but use ranges instead when finding tags.
  If wdrngStart.Find.Execute(findText:="<ANSWERS>", MatchCase:=False) Then
     ' found!
     wdrngAnswers.Start = wdrngStart.End
     If wdrngEnd.Find.Execute(findText:="</ANSWERS>", MatchCase:=False) Then
        wdrngAnswers.End = wdrngEnd.Start
        bGoOn = True
     Else
        ' no closing tag found
        bGoOn = False
     End If
  Else
     'no opening tag found
     bGoOn = False
  End If

If bGoOn Then
   For Each wdTable In wdrngAnswers.Tables
      ' ** below doesn't work anymore: object doesn't support this method **
      For Each wdRow In wdTable
         ' as example, take column 4 of each row
         strStr = wdRow.Cells(4).Range.Text
         strStr = Left(strStr, Len(strStr) - 2) ' remove end of cell markers
         Debug.Print strStr
      Next
   Next
   CreateSEWorksheet = True
Else
   CreateSEWorksheet = False
End If

End Function
```